# How can I map multiple keys to the same value in a distributed environment?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, synchronized, multimap

I'd like to discuss implementions of a map mapping multiple keys mapped to the same value in a distributed environment.

One method of implementing this(that I don't like) (in Java):

```
class ConcurrentMultiKeyMap<K1, K2, V> {
    HashMap<K1, K2> map1to2 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<K2, K1> map2to1 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<K1, V> mapToV = new HashMap<>();

    public synchronized V put(K1 k1, K2 k2, V v) {
        K2 previousK2 = map1to2.get(k1);
        K1 previousK1 = map2to1.get(k2);
        mapToV.remove(previousK1);
        map1to2.remove(previousK1);
        map2to1.remove(previousK2);
        map1to2.put(k1, k2);
        map2to1.put(k2, k1);
        return mapToV.put(k1, v);
    }
    synchronized void remove(K1 k1) {
        K2 k2 = map1to2.remove(k1);
        map2to1.remove(k2);
        mapToV.remove(k1);
    }
    synchronized void remove(K2 k2) {
        K1 k1 = map2to1.remove(k2);
        map1to2.remove(k1);
        mapToV.remove(k1);
    }
    synchronized V get(K1 k1) {
        return mapToV.get(k1);
    }
    synchronized V getBy2(K2 k2) {
        K1 k1 = map2to1.get(k2);
        if(k1 != null)
            return getBy1(k1);
        else
            return null;
    }



    public synchronized boolean containsBy1(K1 k1) {
        return map1to2.containsKey(k1);
    }
    public synchronized boolean containsBy2(K2 k2) {
        return map2to1.containsKey(k2);
    }
    public synchronized V[] values(V[] empty_va) {
        return mapToV.values().toArray(empty_va);
    }
    public synchronized int size() {
        return mapToV.size();
    }
    public synchronized boolean isEmpty() {
        return mapToV.isEmpty();
    }

    public synchronized void clear() {
        mapToV.clear();
        map1to2.clear();
        map2to1.clear();
    }

    @Override public synchronized String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("BadConcurrentMultiKeyMap{");
        for(Map.Entry<K1, V> entry : mapToV.entrySet()) {
            builder.append("(");
            K1 k1 = entry.getKey();
            K2 k2 = map1to2.get(k1);
            V v = entry.getValue();
            builder.append("k1=").append(k1).append(",");
            builder.append("k2=").append(k2).append(",");
            builder.append("v=").append(v);
            builder.append("), ");
        }
        if(!isEmpty()) builder.delete(builder.length()-2, builder.length());
        builder.append("}");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    @Test public void demonstration() {
        ConcurrentMultiKeyMap<Integer, String, String> map = new ConcurrentMultiKeyMap<>();

        map.put(1, "1", "v1");
        map.put(2, "2", "v2");
        assertEquals("v1", map.getBy1(1));
        assertEquals("v1", map.getBy2("1"));
        assertEquals("v2", map.getBy1(2));
        assertEquals("v2", map.getBy2("2"));
        assertNull(map.getBy1(3));
        assertNull(map.getBy2("3"));

        map.removeBy1(1);
        assertNull(map.getBy1(1));
        assertNull(map.getBy2("1"));

        map.removeBy2("2");
        assertNull(map.getBy1(2));
        assertNull(map.getBy2("2"));


        map.put(1, "A", "v1");
        System.out.println("map = " + map);
        map.put(2, "A", "v2");
        System.out.println("map = " + map);
        map.removeBy1(1);
        System.out.println("map = " + map);
        System.out.println("map.mapToV = " + map.mapToV);
        System.out.println("map.map1to2 = " + map.map1to2);
        System.out.println("map.map2to1 = " + map.map2to1);

        map.clear();

        map.put(1, "A", "v1");
        System.out.println("map = " + map);
        map.put(2, "A", "v2");
        System.out.println("map = " + map);
        map.removeBy2("A");
        System.out.println("map = " + map);
        System.out.println("map.mapToV = " + map.mapToV);
        System.out.println("map.map1to2 = " + map.map1to2);
        System.out.println("map.map2to1 = " + map.map2to1);
    }
}
```

Does anyone knwo a **better** solution? Bonus points if it were to work for a variable number of keys and use a smart locking scheme.

**NOTE:** The solution is required to allow access by either key separately. So a traditional CompositeKey does not work, since the hash code cannot be calculated with only either key.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you look at existing solutions like Cassandra and how they deal with composite keys? Please describe *in question* what approaches are you familiar with and why they are not good enough for you?

Comment: Composite Key is a good starting point for me, thanks. I guess I could just create such a composite key object whenever I need such a multi-key-map.
The only problem being new object creation for every lookup...

Comment: Actually neverming.. Composite keys are not the way to go as there is no way to use either key separately. In fact I have not found a working, existing solution. If you could point me to one I would be very happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: The method names are inconsistent, `get` vs `getBy1` and `remove` vs `removeBy1` and `removeBy2`. Besides, the semantics of this key duality is not clear, `map.put(1, "A", "v1");` → `{1=v1, A=v1}`, `map.put(2, "A", "v2");` → `{1=v1, 2=v2, A=v2}`, `map.removeBy1(1);` → `{2=v2}`…

Comment: I feel weird defending something I explicitly don't like, but here we go: The 'inconistent' method names are due to Java's generics. Your example does not work like that. Instead the result will be: {2=v2,A=v2}. Had you done map.removeBy2("A"), the result would however be a little peculiar as only one entry with A as the key would be removed.

Comment: OK, sorry. You were kinda right: I have updated the put method to remove previous entries if the exist under one of the two keys. But honestly my goal is not really to improve the existing design, but to find a fundamentally better one - if that exists.